# Include errors when building python wheel using Cmake and Pybind

Tags: cmake, build, pybind11, python-wheel

I'm trying to make a pip package from c++ project with pybind11 python bindings. However, every time I try to build the wheel, I get include errors, no matter what I try.

Things I've tried:
Project structure:

```
src/
   header1.hpp
   header2.hpp
   mainheader.hpp
   mainfile.cpp
   pythonbindings.cpp
```

in mainheader:
`#include "header1.hpp"` or `#include "src/header1.hpp"` or `#include "./header1.hpp"`

Other project structure I've tried (generated by cookiecutter cpp project):

```
include/
   header1.hpp
   header2.hpp
   mainheader.hpp
python/
   pythonbindings.cpp
src/
   mainfile.cpp
```

I have a setup.py and a pyproject.toml. I try to run `python3 -m build`, but EVERY SINGLE TIME I get an include error for either mainheader.hpp (top project structure) or header1.hpp (bottom project structure).
If you need to see my cmake/setup/pyproject files, please let me know and I'll add them.

Comment: add the actual error you're getting to your question

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your CMakeLists.txt

Otherwise take a look at this template project: https://github.com/mizux/cmake-pybind11